# REST: How can I delete a resource and optionally delete another one?

Tags: rest, http

I need to delete some resource, but I'd like to let the client decide if to also delete a related resource along with it or leave it.

For example, suppose I have some project which holds several customers. When I want to delete the project, I would like to specify in the request whether to delete its associated customers or not.

So I ask if I can do something like this:

```
DELETE http://..../.../someproject?deletecustomers=true
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the few constraints the REST architecture puts onto the overall design is caching. Caching in HTTP works on the whole URI which acts as cache key where the value corresponds to the cached representation response. Any unsafe operation performed on that URI, such as POST, PUT, DELETE, ..., will lead to an eviciton of that stored response (also if a certain time threshold is exceeded). On appending further parameters to the URI, the cache, which acts de facto on the full URI, might not find a resource representation therefore to evict. A further problem with deleting an asscociated resource in the background is, that it bypasses any caches so they wont take notice of that deletion in first place and might serve clients still with the outdated response. As such, especially if the client is in control of deciding whether to delete an associated resource as well, it is better to issue a second DELETE request.

Note  that `DELETE` is defined to only remove the URI mapping of that resource, so that a successive request on the same URI does not return the data of that resource, but that does not necessarily mean that data of that resource was removed from the system. Usually, though, that data is also removed as part of the `DELETE` operation. This is a perfect example that certain things in a REST architecture are implementation dependent which behave transparent to clients, meaning that they don't really know how a remote system truely behaves.